# Installing an anti-virus on a computer that doesn't not have internet.

Tags: anti-virus

I work for a government agency and our classroom computers don't connect to the internet. Somehow our usb flash drives became infected with a virus. We have since removed the virus from the usb flash using our personal laptops but now the classroom computer is infected with the virus. So of course everytime we use our flash we get the virus again.... is there a way to install an anti-virus on the stand alone computer? I remember back in the day having anti virus on a cd but can't seem to find them in the shops here. (We live in the midllde east)

Comment: Most of these anti-virus companie offer a license and will cover your need.  It will allow you to to publish the updates from your own version, an outdated security software, is as useless as not having one.  Because MSE updates are published over Windows Update its likely your best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used any of these tools myself but you might have some success with these portable tools.

http://portableapps.com/apps/security

It should be possible to install an anti virus tool which runs from a USB memory stick (or similar) using one of these tools.

These tools won't be the same as having an anti virus "installed" onto the PC which monitors your machine in real time, but will give you the chance to scan and hopefully clean.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a livecd for virus removal, but there is a [list](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/13-antivirus-rescue-cds-software-compared-in-search-for-the-best-rescue-disk/) with annotations on how they differ. Just try what suits your need best.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is easy to solve.

Get [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), [Malwarebytes Anti-Rootkit BETA](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/mbar/), [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-download). Download them on another computer.

Get a blank CD, [burn them](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/videos/burn-a-cd#tab=pictures), it will ask you, if you want to burn them or if you want to use the CD like a USB, select "use the CD as a USB", put the cd in the other computer and install them.

Note, it's better to scan in safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

I would either :

- Use an antivirus LiveCD like BitDefender's (see @Tim's answer)
- Find a cleanc omputer, format a flash drive, install a portable version of a free antivirus on it (Like ClamWin portable, which uses ClamAV engine) and use it on each computer to clean it, hoping it is able too cure this particular infection.

Answer (score 0):

Might even have left the school by now lol.

Try using [Smadav anti-virus](http://www.smadav.net/?lang=en&_sm_byp=iVVFRWqGKkjnrLP2)

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution, providing value beyond a random Google hit. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.